# I converted a int to a str but I get "object of type 'int' has no len()"

Tags: python, string, int

This function is supposed to return the sum of digits of a number.

I converted the new variable into a string using `new = str(x)`

```
def digital_root(x):
    sum=0
    new = str(x)
    while len(new) > 2:
        for i in new:
            sum = sum + int(i)
        new = sum

    if len(str(new))==2:
        return int(new[0])+int(new[1])
```

Called with e.g. `digital_root(65536)`. But it returns:

> TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: As a hint: when you say `new = sum`, what type does `new` now have?

Comment: When posting questions about errors, please post the full error trace, starting from `Traceback (most recent call last)` until the end

Comment: `digital_root = lambda x: sum(map(int, str(x)))`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you converted your variable, so when you first enter the `while` loop, it's a string.

However, inside the loop you do `new = sum`, where `sum` is of type `int`. So second check of the loop breaks because `object of type 'int' has no len()`.

What you want is:

```
def digital_root(x):
    sum=0
    new = str(x)
    while len(new) > 2:
        for i in new:
            sum = sum + int(i)
        new = str(sum) # make sure each time you leave, your type is str

    if len(new)==2: # here you don't have to make it a string anymore
        return int(new[0])+int(new[1])
```